# How can I make my Attack Combo System more modular?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Working on a beat em up. I've fleshed out a basic way to handle attack combos. I'm looking for a better way to handle modularity when adding new moves and making the logic more concise.

```
public class Attack : AbstractBehavior
{

public bool attack1;
public bool attack2;
public bool attack3;

public int currentAttack = 0;
public float lastAttackTime;
public float attackDelay = 0.2f;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    var canAttack = inputState.GetButtonValue(InputButtons[0]);
    var holdTime = inputState.GetButtonHoldtime(InputButtons[0]);

    if (canAttack && currentAttack == 0 && holdTime < 0.1f)
    {
        attack1 = true;
        currentAttack++;
        lastAttackTime = Time.time;
    }

    if (canAttack && currentAttack == 1 && holdTime < 0.1f && Time.time - lastAttackTime > attackDelay)
    {
        attack1 = false;
        attack2 = true;
        currentAttack++;
        lastAttackTime = Time.time;
    }

    if (canAttack && currentAttack == 2 && holdTime < 0.1f && Time.time - lastAttackTime > attackDelay)
    {
        attack2 = false;
        attack3 = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have working code that you're just looking to improve, your question is more suitable for [codereview.se].

Comment: use an array `bool[] attacks` instead multiple numbered variables and use a `for` loop to deal with the update logic

Comment: You could remove the input logic from the class, and have some triggers to the attacks instead. So, the Input could be made from an input controller class, that calls for a hit; the combo class checks if it is a hot and performs the action

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a "tree" of `AttackComboUnits`, where you nest what comes after what. Then, in main `Attack` script, you hold the initial attack combo unit and the one that's currently active.

**NOTE:** it's just a concept idea, script might not work as they were writen inside Notepad++ and I haven't tested them.

```
public class AttackComboUnit : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    privaet bool baseComboUnit;
    [SerializeField]
    private AttackComboUnit nextUnit;
    [SerializeField]
    private float maxDelay;

    private Animator animator;
    private float enableTime;





    private void OnEnable()
    {
        enableTime = Time.time;
    }




    public AttackComboUnit Attack()
    {
        // Player didn't use attack for too long and this is not base attack unit, so delay must be applied
        if(!baseComboUnit)
        {
            if(Time.time - enableTime > maxDelay)
                return null;
        }


        animator.Play("myAwesomeComboSkill");

        // // // // // // // // // // // // //
        // Do some damage or something else //
        // // // // // // // // // // // // //

        return nextUnit;
    }
}





public class Attack : AbstractBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private AttackComboUnit initialAttackUnit;

    private AttackComboUnit currentAttackUnit;





    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(canAttack && holdTime < 0.1f)
        {
            AttackComboUnit comboUnit = currentAttackUnit.Attack();
            SetAttackUnit(comboUnit);
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        currentAttackUnit = initialAttackUnit;
    }





    private void SetAttackUnit(AttackComboUnit attackComboUnit)
    {
        currentAttackUnit.enabled = false;
        currentAttackUnit = attackComboUnit;
        attackComboUnit.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Now just place all the `AttackComboUnit`s on the `GameObject`, ant assign what goes after what. Adjust delays. Delay is counted from when the script is enabled. Disable all attacks except the initial one.

You could also add field for name of animation that should be played, so that your `AttackComboUnit` script becomes more generic.